# How to set dynamic div height based on screen resolution using angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to set a div height based on screen resolution. I am using angular 5 for coding. Even when the screen is zoomed in or zoomed out the div height should fit the place

This is my html part

```
<div [style.height.px]="divHeight">
</div>
```

And in my ts file

```
this.divHeight= window.innerHeight - 202;
```

This works only when my screen is 100% zoom. I need the div height adjusted even when the screen is zoomed in or zoomed out. Plz help me out.

Comment: If it's dynamic, you probably don't mean screen resolution but viewport resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the `vh` property -- perhaps with `calc`?

```
div.thatShallNotBeNamed {
   height: calc(100vh - 202px);
}
```

Edit:
`vh` stands for "view height." It also has a corresponding property for "view width" called `vw`

Comment: 'vw' and 'vh are part of the Viewport Units available in major browsers with CSS3. You can read more about them here: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/ And find browser support here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: What is special about 202px?

Comment: @AnandRaj Idk. It's just the amount he had in his question: `this.divHeight= window.innerHeight - 202;`

Answer (score 1):

Window.innerHeight work for even zoom out and zoom in as well.

I assume the problem your are facing is you are not resetting height for div when you zoom in or out, you can use host listener for this purpose.

```
@HostListener("window:resize")
onResize() {
    this.divHeight = window.innerHeight - 202;  
}
```